# Match strings in two columns with the highest string similiarity ratio-pandas

Tags: python, string, difflib

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                   'name1': ['A brewery', 'B fresh produce', '100 wines', 'C canzirri ', 'D company']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   'name2': ['bvb breweries', 'A brewerIES', 'BBBB fresh produce', '100 wines', 'f C canzirri ', 'Dcompany', 'b fresh produce']})
```

I want to generate new column `df1.similar`, for each `df1.name1` value, the `df1.similar` is the corresponding value from `df2.name2` with the highest similarity ratio.

The  `df1.ratio`  contains the highest similarity ratio.

For example:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def similiarity_ratio(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

s=[]
for i in df2['name2']:
  s.append(similiarity_ratio('A brewery',i))
max(s)
```

The desirable output will set 'A brewerIES' (in df2.name2) to `df1.similar`, 0.8 to `df1.ratio`.

How can I apply/lamda to do it cross all values in `df1.name1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have had a try by myself. Silly but seems ok.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher


def compare(a):
    compare={}
    for i in df2['name2']:
        compare.update({i: SequenceMatcher(None, a, i).ratio()})
    item = max(compare, key=compare.get)
    max_ratio = max(compare.values())
    return pd.Series([item, max_ratio],
                     index=['matched name', 'highest_similarity ratio'])


df1[['matched name', 'highest_similarity ratio']] = df1['name1'].apply(lambda x: compare(x))
df1
```

But I just learnt that it can be much easier if use `difflib.get_close_matches`.